# Cocoa ScreenSaverView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, screensaver

I am trying to play with `ScreenSaverView` in mac OS X.

I followed this tutorial http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000088.php 
and it worked (can't say flawlessly ,but worked).
I also saw in part 2 of this tutorial they are playing with openGL stuff etc.

I have 2 general questions:

1)Can I use SprteKit within screensaver view?

2)What is wrong with my code here -> it compiles well, however I don't see anything except a black screen (I want to see my *.png).

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame isPreview:(BOOL)isPreview
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame isPreview:isPreview];
    if (self)
    {
        _imageView = [[NSImageView alloc]initWithFrame:[self bounds]];
        [_imageView setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"SettingsButton.png"]];
        [self addSubview:_imageView];
        [self setAnimationTimeInterval:1.0];
    }
    return self;
}
```

EDIT: Attempt to use a draw rect:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect0
{
    [super drawRect:rect0];

    NSImage *anotherImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"SettingsButton.png"];
    [anotherImage drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(10,100) fromRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,[anotherImage size].width,[anotherImage size].height) operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];


    // Calculate a random color
    CGFloat red = SSRandomFloatBetween( 0.0, 255.0 ) / 255.0;
    CGFloat green = SSRandomFloatBetween( 0.0, 255.0 ) / 255.0;
    CGFloat blue = SSRandomFloatBetween( 0.0, 255.0 ) / 255.0;

    NSColor* color = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:red
                                  green:green
                                   blue:blue
                                  alpha:1];


    NSColor * color2 = [NSColor colorWithPatternImage:anotherImage];
    [color2 set];

    NSBezierPath * path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rect0];
   [path fill];
}
```

When I set a color it works , I can see a screen filled by Random colors (fine as meant)

When I use color2 which is a pattern from the image 
nothing is works :-( -> I tried different images 
same nothing there...

I checked in build phase that I do copy the images as a bundle resources

What could be the problem ?

EDIT: Ok so after my attempt in drawRect I suspected that `imageNamed` method is causing a troubles and rewrite my origin attempt to:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame isPreview:(BOOL)isPreview
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame isPreview:isPreview];
    if (self)
    {
        _imageView = [[NSImageView alloc]initWithFrame:[self bounds]];
        NSBundle * tempBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];

    // Load your image, "top.tiff". Don't forget to release it when you are done (not shown).
        NSImage * theImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
                          [tempBundle pathForImageResource:@"personal1.jpg"]];
        [_imageView setImage:theImage];
        [self addSubview:_imageView];
        [self setAnimationTimeInterval:1.0];

    }
    return self;
}
```

And Whoaallaaa it worked !!(Kinda) I see my picture :-) !!!

As for part1 of the Question -> Yes it is possible 
Just tried and it works ! 
with a little down side I can exit ScreenSaver only with cmd key xD

Managed to solve this issue,by subclassing `SKView` and delivering event to the next responder.

However it gave me a huge idea -> actually it just opens an opportunity to make a simple SK game as part of the screensaver could have been a cute feature.

Sadly I can't submit it to app store :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me if a SpriteKit view (`SKView`) can even be used in a normal OSX/iOS app.  I have searched in the past and found nothing.

If SpriteKit is anything like other game frameworks (from which it borrows much of its structure) then it will use a traditional game loop; i.e. clear screen, draw everything, wait a bit and then repeat.

Cocoa apps use an runloop that reacts to events and take steps to only redraw what needs to be redrawn.

So I would say "No" to your first question.

As far as your second, code-related, question is concerned, then I cannot see much wrong with it, however I am not familiar with that `init` method; what class does it subclass?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ScreenSaver/Classes/ScreenSaverView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ScreenSaverView/animateOneFrame

Comment: @user3351949 Well as I say, I don't see too much wrong with it.  Are you sure the image is being loaded successfully?

Comment: In Xcode 6 (latest) open new project OS X system plugins and you will find screensaver there -> so it is straight forward from the template... I really don't know much more, I don't know how to debug it, how to log events etc... this is entire new thing for me, and still IDK why I can't see my picture:'(

Comment: Well if you can run it within Xcode (I've never done it myself) then you will see logged messages in the Xcode console.  So load the image into an object reference first and log that reference: `NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"SettingsButton.png"]; NSLog(@"Image=%@", image); [_imageView setImage:image];`.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to do so, when I try to "play" the project
it only builds an .saver file , which installs the screen saver to system preferences... Any idea how can I see log from there?

Comment: It's a bit of a pain if you're new to coding as it looks like you'd need to use `asl_log()` or something similar...

Comment: I am not that new in coding :-) i just always had a debuger :)

Comment: hmm I will try to dump a custom log in to file :-) I will update you as soon as i will success

Comment: The thing that bothers me a lot is ... when i implemented the drawRect like here http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000088.php it actually worked ...

maybe this thing doesn't support layers and subviews ?!? but where to get answer for it ? since there is nothing like that said in documentations

Comment: The opening sentence on the link in your first comment shows the two ways to draw into a screensaver.

Comment: I just figured it and tried a things , let me a minute to update the question :)

Comment: I have updated the Question -> seems like there is a problem with images :-( (I tried 3 different images) none worked... or maybe i still do something wrong ?